# designed for iPad and iPhone fonts display different issues in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit


struct HTMLView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var html: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let styledHTML = """
        <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                /* Your CSS styles here */
                \(try! String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ncecd", withExtension: "css")!))
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            \(html)
        </body>
        </html>
        """
        uiView.loadHTMLString(styledHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: CoreDataViewModel
    var word: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HTMLView(html: vm.wordMeanings(keyword: word) ?? "")
                .font(.custom("HelveticaNeue", size: 48))
                .fontWeight(.black)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Text("\(word)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .lineLimit(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why fonts are designed for iPad and iPhone display differently. I set the size to 48, I don't know why.

I mean, meaning to get the content is html tag, through the css style to parse out the content

But I found that the two devices display different fonts

I wanna solve the problem of font display size (designed for iPad and iphone)

css:

```css
.header{
    margin-top: 12px;
    font-size: 48px;
    display: block;
    font-size: large;
    display: none;
}
.jianhu_syn:before{
    display: block;
    content: "同义词：";
    color: black;
}
.jianhu_syn{
    margin-top: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #942923;
}
.jianhu_exa{
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    
}
.jianhu_exa:before{
    counter-increment:def;
    content:counter(def) ". ";
    padding-left: 24px;
}

.jianhu_def{
    margin-top: 28px;
    counter-reset:def;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #2a5598;
    background-color: rgba(87, 139, 197, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    font-weight: 530;
}
```

html:

```html
<style type="text/css"></style><link href="ncecd.css" rel="stylesheet"/><span class="header">不上道子</span><div class="jianhu_def">就是指不讲道理。</div><div class="jianhu_exa">他那个人又不上道子，你跟他能说出个什呢米搞豆子来呀？</div><div class="jianhu_exa">那么大的岁数不上道子，他不是把一把年纪活作得了吗？</div>
```

[iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYBBM.jpg)

[designed for iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tceZG.png)

Comment: designed for the iPad, the font is normal, but phones is pretty small

Comment: Could it be that your frame for the Text() is not as wide as you expect it to be and the .lineLimit(1) is shrinking the text to fit?
Yout could try to set a background color to the text to see its real size.

Comment: I probably didn't make it very clear, I mean HTMLView

Comment: This is a Text():
Text("\(word)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .lineLimit(1)

Comment: Ah, you mean the text inside the html view?
Did you try to add a background color under the frame to check the size of it?

Comment: I just added two pictures

Comment: I'm just trying to solve the problem of different font sizes

Comment: The font displayed on the phone is too small, if I set font size in CSS file, it may be larger than the standard size, but it is designed for the iPad to display larger. I want to set the display font size the same on different devices